# Save a node from another site

Tags: 7, services

I have a newspaper web based management system that allow users to manage articles and news and photo album using J2EE (Internal system to the newspaper)

I need to make a website using drupal 7 to this newspaper

I need to make a button in the J2EE system that will save a node in my site(plain text,Full html test,files like images and pdf)

So I need to make a webservice in my drupal site and call it from the J2EE

Is there any module that help me in this issue,if not how to customize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) will definitely help you with that

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the same callback code.

It has CRUD operations for nodes, files, users and plenty more. There's a [video presentation](http://drupal.org/project/services) available that introduces it properly, and there are loads of code samples on the web to get you started.

Comment: Think you forgot to add hyperlink to video :)